# Dart/Flutter List -> setting Selected Category

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a menu that's state is set by tapping it's own items, *the menuButton in this instance.

I have create the menu by calling a listview and creating a repeatable menuButton where I pass button specific info.

The selected menuButton's font will be a larger size

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:theboardwalk/ConsumerSide/mainConsumerScreen.dart';

class homeMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const homeMenu({Key key, String category}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _homeMenuState createState() => _homeMenuState();
}

class _homeMenuState extends State<homeMenu> {
   bool isSelected;


  Padding menuButton(BuildContext context, String category, IconData categoryIcon) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .225,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () =>
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                if (category == 'Home') {
                  return mainConsumerScreen();
                } else {
                  return mainConsumerScreen();
                }
              })),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
             Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .1,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .2,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Colors.deepPurple, Colors.deepPurpleAccent],
                    ),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                    categoryIcon,
                    size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .12,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
              child: Text(
                    category,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                      fontSize: isSelected ? 16 : 18,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .005),
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .16,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .96,
        child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: <Widget>[
          menuButton(context, 'Home', Icons.home),
          menuButton(context, 'Eat', Icons.restaurant_menu),
          menuButton(context, 'Shop', Icons.store),
          menuButton(context, 'Travel', Icons.airplanemode_active),
          menuButton(context, 'Play', Icons.local_activity),
          menuButton(context, 'Services', Icons.build),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how do I pass the state back to itself?
On press setState of the ListView and have listview then have the button listen for isSelected bool?

Afterwards I am going to use the homeMenu's state to set the state of a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

complete solution is here - https://github.com/aaronksaunders/flutter_drawer_detail

Set up the provider at top level of app

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      providers: <SingleChildCloneableWidget>[
        ChangeNotifierProvider<DrawerStateInfo>(
            builder: (_) => DrawerStateInfo()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

but the main idea is to create a provider object that manages the state

```
class DrawerStateInfo with ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentDrawer = 0;
  int get getCurrentDrawer => _currentDrawer;

  void setCurrentDrawer(int drawer) {
    _currentDrawer = drawer;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

get the state in the drawer

```
var currentDrawer = Provider.of<DrawerStateInfo>(context).getCurrentDrawer;
```

And set the state in the drawer

```
Provider.of<DrawerStateInfo>(context).setCurrentDrawer(0);
```